# Slow initial website load, faster subsequent loads

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, apc, plesk

My site www.slople.com is a mix of self-programmed things (the whole slope-finder etc and the mobile-site) and Wordpress/Buddypress-things (Slople Unity, Blog).

I notice that the page takes longer to load on the first request, no matter where it goes (startpage, particular slope, blog) than subsequent pageloads.

The site is running on my "own" VPS with CentOS and Plesk 11. I use APC, nginx, Apache, MySql and PHP 5.1

I suppose some of you could have an idea where I'd have to look into or what could be the cause. I always think it could depend on my DNS (I run my own DNS-service with plesk).

The machine is powerful enough, never uses more than 1/3 of it's RAM. Thanks for any inputs!

Comment: Same problem here using Plesk 12, Nginx and Apache, have you found a solution @Raphael Jeger?

Answer (score 1):

Try "Page Speed" tab of FireBug.

As I see your server has no gzip compression for static content. Compression can be [switched on in nginx config](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpGzipModule).

Also, website has a lot of separate PNG, CSS and JS  files. I know some CMS templates allows to gather all JS and CSS in single files. PNG files also can be gathered in single file.

Comment: thank you for your input Oleg. I know about the problem with lots of separate files, this is still on my todo list. What does "static content" mean? Is it smart enough to detect that my pages (almost all of them) are highly dynamic, or does that only cache static resources like images, js + css etc? Do you mean something like this: http://www.howtoforge.com/make-browsers-cache-static-files-on-nginx

Comment: I'm talking about this nginx module http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpGzipModule. I think nginx can recognize resource mime type and compress it, anyway it's not difficult to check. If it's actually is, you can play with "gzip_comp_level" directive to set up proper (speed/size) level of compression.

Comment: I'll read into that, thank you! However, I still fear it could by the DNS resolving. Have you tested the page yourself? If you access the site, the first request takes 1.5-2s. The seconds is way faster (same or different page). Now if you wait again for 40-50 seconds, the next request is like the first...?

Comment: I have tested web site from two different ISP and I can't say that your site is "slow". FireBug shows that it's take 3.14 sec for load - not actually a lot, industry standard is about 2 sec(google.com loads in 1.34 sec for me). Can't say anything about DNS.